# Create Grouped List using LINQ based on related objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following classes (simplified for clarity):

```
public class Rule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name  { get; set; }

    public List<RuleTemplate> RuleTemplates { get; set; }
}

public class RuleTemplate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Rule Rule { get; set; }

    public string Description  { get; set; }
}

public class RuleInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string RuleValue { get; set; }

    public RuleTemplate RuleTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine I have the following data associated with these objects:

**Rule**

Id: 1 / Name: "Between Days of Week"

Id: 2 / Name: "Match Category Id"

**RuleTemplate**

Id: 1 / Rule: (Assigned above Rule Id 1) / Description: "From Day of Week"

Id: 2 / Rule: (Assigned above Rule Id 1) / Description: "To Day of Week"

Id: 3 / Rule: (Assigned above Rule Id 2) / Description: "Category Id"

**RuleInstance**

Id: 1 / RuleValue: "Monday" / RuleTemplate: (Assigned above RuleTemplate Id 1)

Id: 2 / RuleValue: "Friday" / RuleTemplate: (Assigned above RuleTemplate Id 2)

Id: 3 / RuleValue: 300 / RuleTemplate: (Assigned above RuleTemplate Id 3)

So here I've basically got 2 different `Rules`.

The first `Rule` has 2 `RuleTemplates` assigned to it (and each of those `RuleTemplates` has 1 `RuleInstance` assigned).

The second `Rule` has just 1 `RuleTemplate` assigned to it, which has 1 `RuleInstance` assigned to that.

So, if I have a `List<RuleInstance>` based on the above data, **I want to be able to then produce a `List<Rule>` with grouped underlying `RuleTemplates`** (and each of those grouped `RuleTemplates` to have the associated `RuleInstances` attached).

So in this case I would have a List of 2 `Rules` and the associated objects would look something like the following:

```
--Rule Id 1

----RuleTemplate Id 1

------RuleInstance Id 1

----RuleTemplate Id 2

------RuleInstance Id 2

--Rule Id 2

----RuleTemplate Id 3

------RuleInstance Id 3
```

Comment: Why not just do `LstRuleInstance.Select(ri => ri.RuleTemplate.Rule).Distinct()` With that simple line you get the desired `List<Rule>` isn't it?

Comment: Major oversight on my part. Doh! Thanks. If you put this as an answer I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: Sometimes we don't lack of knowledge we only need another pair or eyes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple and straight line you can achieve the desired result:

```
LstRuleInstance.Select(ri => ri.RuleTemplate.Rule).Distinct();
```

That would get you the `List<Rule>` from a `List<RuleInstance>`.